# Break down a long string into multiple lists

Tags: python-3.x, string, dataframe, split

Is there a simple way to break down this string into multiple lists in Python so that I can then create a dataframe with those lists?

1|Mirazur|Menton, France|2|Noma|Copenhagen, Denmark|3|Asador Etxebarri|Axpe, Spain|4|Gaggan|Bangkok, Thailand|5|Geranium|Copenhagen, Denmark|6|Central|Lima, Peru|7|Mugaritz|San Sebastián, Spain|8|Arpège|Paris, France|9|Disfrutar|Barcelona, Spain|10|Maido|Lima, Peru|11|Den|Tokyo, Japan

I want to break it down so that it looks like:

```
[1, Mirazur, Menton, France]
[2, Noma, Copenhagen, Denmark]
and so on so forth.
```

I'm really new to all this, so any advice really appreciated. The more simple answer is possible, rather than any 'fancier' ones would be great so that I can understand the more basic concepts first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piece of cake. The basis is splitting on the `|` character; this will give you a flat list of all items. Next, split the list into smaller ones of a fixed size; a well-researched question with lots of answers. I chose https://stackoverflow.com/a/5711993/2564301 because it does not use any external libraries and returns a useful base for the next step:

```
print (zip(*[data.split('|')[i::3] for i in range(3)]))
```

This returns a `zip` type, as can be seen with

```
for item in zip(*[data.split('|')[i::3] for i in range(3)]):
    print (item)
```

which comes pretty close:

```
('1', 'Mirazur', 'Menton, France')
('2', 'Noma', 'Copenhagen, Denmark')
('3', 'Asador Etxebarri', 'Axpe, Spain')
etc.
```

(If you are wondering why `zip` is needed, print the result of `[data.split('|')[i::3] for i in range(3)]`.)

The final step is to convert each tuple into a list of its own.

Putting it together:

```
import pprint

data = '1|Mirazur|Menton, France|2|Noma|Copenhagen, Denmark|3|Asador Etxebarri|Axpe, Spain|4|Gaggan|Bangkok, Thailand|5|Geranium|Copenhagen, Denmark|6|Central|Lima, Peru|7|Mugaritz|San Sebastián, Spain|8|Arpège|Paris, France|9|Disfrutar|Barcelona, Spain|10|Maido|Lima, Peru|11|Den|Tokyo, Japan'

data = [list(item) for item in zip(*[data.split('|')[i::3] for i in range(3)])]
pprint.pprint (data)
```

Result (nice indentation courtesy of [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)):

```
[['1', 'Mirazur', 'Menton, France'],
 ['2', 'Noma', 'Copenhagen, Denmark'],
 ['3', 'Asador Etxebarri', 'Axpe, Spain'],
 ['4', 'Gaggan', 'Bangkok, Thailand'],
 ['5', 'Geranium', 'Copenhagen, Denmark'],
 ['6', 'Central', 'Lima, Peru'],
 ['7', 'Mugaritz', 'San Sebastián, Spain'],
 ['8', 'Arpège', 'Paris, France'],
 ['9', 'Disfrutar', 'Barcelona, Spain'],
 ['10', 'Maido', 'Lima, Peru'],
 ['11', 'Den', 'Tokyo, Japan']]
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. I got as far as the splitting on | but then tried all sorts after and just couldn't get the separate rows. This makes so much sense now that I read it. Thanks a bunch again.